# How can I add a $ sign to Total Gas Cost and Cost Per Mile output?

Tags: python

How can I add a $ in the front of the calculates value. e.g., $ 64.6

```py
# Calculate and display total gas cost`enter code here`
total_gas_cost = round(gallons_used * cost_per_gallon, 2)
print("Total Gas Cost:\t", total_gas_cost)

# Calculate and display cost per mile
cost_per_mile = round(cost_per_gallon / miles_per_gallon)
print("Cost Per Mile:\t", cost_per_mile)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `print("Total Gas Cost:\t$", total_gas_cost)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("Total Gas Cost:\t$ ", total_gas_cost)
```

Or, better:

```
print(f"Total Gas Cost:\t$ {total_gas_cost:.2f}")
```

This is [an f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). The `.2f` after the variable name says, "show 2 decimal places". It's often better to do this than to round the variable itself, which might lead to imprecision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **locale** module:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )

print("Total Gas Cost:", locale.currency(total_gas_cost))
```